# triple nesting issue comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have comments nested inside posts which are nested in games. I cannot for the life of my figure out how to add comments. I'm getting an undefined method.

```
 Showing /Users/***/Documents/TestRoutes/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #31 raised:

undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb2159834a0>:0x007fb215980228>
Extracted source (around line #31):

28: <% end %>
29: 
30: <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
31: <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
32:   <div class="field">
33:     <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
34:     <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
```

`<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>`

```
   resources :games do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end

def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
      redirect_to game_post_path(@post)
    end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :body, :commenter
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post, :title, :game_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it complete posts / comments routes?

```
   resources :games do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
   end
```

If so, you should specify game as well, something like

```
<%= form_for([@game, @post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Same for redirect line

```
redirect_to game_post_path(@post)
```

Without game most likely it will raise an error

Comment: Thanks, that worked! 
I ended up using
  def create
      -@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      -@comment = -@post.comments.create(params[:comment])
      -@game = -@post.game_id
      redirect_to game_post_path(-@game, -@post)
    end

for the redirect because the game_id wasn't getting passed to the post controller.